# Como traer valores de la misma columna pero con distintas condiciones en una query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo que hacer una consulta que relaciona dos tablas, viajes_fases y viajes_fases_detalle. La salida deben ser los nombres de las fases en la primera columna y los nombres de las fases según id_fase_rechazo en la segunda columna. ¿Cómo puedo, en sólo una query, realizar condiciones diferentes para traer el nombre?

El ejemplo de abajo se obtiene de esta query:

```
SELECT vf.nombre,vd.id_fase_rechazo
FROM  viajes_fases_detalle vd, viajes_fases vf
WHERE vd.id_fase = vf.id_fase;
```

pero estoy trayendo el id, que no me sirve.

[image: Tabla viajes_fases, viajes_fases_detalle y salida]

También probé con la siguiente query, pero los datos no son correctos.

```
SELECT vf1.nombre, vf2.nombre
FROM viajes_fases vf1, viajes_fases vf2, viajes_fases_detalle vd
WHERE vd.id_fase = vf1.id_fase
AND vd.id_fase = vf2.id_fase;

La salida esperada es la siguiente:
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Además de los links, alguna de las etiquetas es incorrecta. O el SGBD es `mysql` o es `sql server`. Es importante diferenciar, porque cada uno tiene sus propias particularidades. Si en vez de poner imágenes con lo que tienes, pegas scripts con los datos o un sqlfidle, mejoras la pregunta y cada persona que te quiera ayudar, no tiene que reproducir lo que solicitas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un alias para sacer el nombre de la Fase (**NOMBRE**) a partir del campo `ID_FASE_RECHAZO`, que creo que es lo que necesitas.

Prueba con esta:

```
SELECT VF.NOMBRE, VF2.NOMBRE FROM VIAJES_FASES_DETALLE VD 
LEFT JOIN VIAJES_FASES VF ON VF.ID_FASE=VD.ID_FASE
LEFT JOIN VIAJES_FASES VF2 ON VF2.ID_FASE=VD.ID_FASE_RECHAZO
WHERE VD.ID_FASE = VF.ID_FASE
```